# How to extract/get a xml attribute values to display

Tags: jquery, xml, weather-api

I am trying to integrate **open weather api** in my application and I have invoked weather api and it's returned xml response. But when I am trying to get the values it's throwing error like unknown error.

**My code is:**

**js code:**

```
<script type="application/javascript">

        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=Hyderabad,IN&mode=xml&appid=c9d49310f8023ee2617a7634de23c2aa",
                dataType: "xml",
                success: function(data) {
                    /* handle data here */
                    console.log(data);

                    //$('<p>Text</p>').appendTo('#weather_report');

                    /*var wrapper = $("#weather_report");
                     wrapper.empty();
                     wrapper.append("<div class='city'> <p>Place: " + data.city.name + "</p><p>Country: " + data.city.country + "</p></div>");
                     wrapper.append("<div class='day_1'> <p>Place: " + data.city.name + "</p><p>Country: " + data.city.country + "</p></div>");*/

                },
                error: function(xhr, status) {
                    /* handle error here */
                }
            });
        });

    </script>
```

**above code returning below format:**

[image]

Could you please suggest me how to get the xml values to display?

Comment: **[jQuery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)**

Comment: @ShaunakD, have you tried it's not working. even though I have tried before you post above method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a hidden `div` on the page, then use the `JQuery.load` method to insert the XML elements into the div. Once you've done that, you can traverse and modify it as you would with HTML. See below code:

`$('#hiddenDivId').load('xmlURL');`

This will insert the XML into the hiddenDiv.

For example, if you have this XML:

```
<foos>
  <foo>
    <prop1>Test</prop1>
    <prop2>Test1</prop2>
  </foo>
</foos>
```

And you then do `$('#hiddenDivId').load('foos.xml');`

The HTML element 'hiddenDivId' would look like this:

```
<div id="hiddenDivId">
  <foos>
    <foo>
      <prop1>Test</prop1>
      <prop2>Test1</prop2>
    </foo>
  </foos>
</div>
```

After that, you can iterate through the element of 'foo' like this:

```
$('#hiddenDivId foos foo').each(function(){
  //you can then do whatever you want with the current 'foo'.
  //to access it from the loop, use the $(this) keyword
  //you can access the properties using $(this).children('property name')
  //and it will treat it like a HTML element
})
```

Comment: how to get those values?

Comment: You can use JQuery selectors. Allow me to update the answer